# Duplicate Font Awesome icons showing up in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Im using Font Awesome icons in my JSP page , However IE shows addtional icon-16 icon-plus-sign in application.
I have found the solution by referring to the 
**[Duplicated icon issue with Twitter Bootstrap and Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452356/duplicated-icon-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-and-font-awesome)**

I tried to add the following to my **bootstrap.css** but didnt help

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]{
    background:none;
  }
```

Im not sure How I do add the following to the font-awesome.css and the bootstrap.css

```
<style type="text/css"> .icon {background:none;} </style>
```

My JSP code that uses the Font Awesome icons "icon-16 icon-plus-sign" is as below

```
<h:grid-check isCheckBoxRequired="false" checkedValue="${user.id}" id="user-${user.username}"/>
                <h:grid-expand  rowId="${user.id}"
                                childUrl="/admin/user/list/${user.id}/children.json"
                                expandClass="icon-16 icon-plus-sign"
                                collapseClass="icon-16 icon-minus-sign"/>
```

However IE shows addtional icon-16 icon-plus-sign in application.
The generated HTML code for IE while Debugging shows **two**

**Internet Explorer**

```
<td style="padding-top: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px; padding-left: 2px;">
    <a href="#" grid-child-url="/admin/user/list/25766383920481368/children.json" grid-expand="25766383920481368">
        <i class="icon-16 icon-plus-sign" data-alt-class="icon-16 icon-minus-sign"/>
<i class="icon-16 icon-plus-sign" data-alt-class="icon-16 icon-minus-sign"/>
```

Comment: Should I add
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]{
    background:none;
  }
To font-awesome.css ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use separate closing tag for icon like this,

```
<i class="icon-16 icon-plus-sign"></i>
```

So try like this,

```
<h:grid-check isCheckBoxRequired="false" checkedValue="${user.id}" id="user-${user.username}"> </h:grid-check> 
<h:grid-expand rowId="${user.id}" childUrl="/admin/user/list/${user.id}/children.json" expandClass="icon-16 icon-plus-sign" collapseClass="icon-16 icon-minus-sign"> </h:grid-expand>
```

Comment: my JSp page the code is 
<h:grid-check isCheckBoxRequired="false" checkedValue="${user.id}" id="user-${user.username}"/>
                <h:grid-expand  rowId="${user.id}"
                                childUrl="/admin/user/list/${user.id}/children.json"
                                expandClass="icon-16 icon-plus-sign"
                                collapseClass="icon-16 icon-minus-sign"/>

Comment: How would I use your suggestion ?

Comment: @ronan I don't know jsp, anyway try like this. ``<h:grid-check isCheckBoxRequired="false" checkedValue="${user.id}" id="user-${user.username}">
</h:grid-check>
<h:grid-expand  rowId="${user.id}"
                                childUrl="/admin/user/list/${user.id}/children.json"
                                expandClass="icon-16 icon-plus-sign"
                                collapseClass="icon-16 icon-minus-sign">
</h:grid-expand>``

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the Twitter Bootstrap css without the icon part.

they provide a version specially for this case

As you can see there are 3 main version of the CSS :

- complete : main + responsive + icon
- without icon : main + responsive
- without responsive behavior : main + icon

[link](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#legacy_tab)

//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css

Note clear your browser cash for any of the solution posted on other forums

Answer (score -1):

Just add  display: block; and height:0 to ico styles in css.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.